# Changing title on legend in order for them to be in row and not in column of QGIS print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

The generic order of the layers in the print composer are in a column.

[image]

I need them to be in a row.

How do I it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I head look into it and there is a built-in function in the print composer in the Qgis software.
Once you click the legend table a toolbar will open on the right.
The "Columns" default is on "1" so you have all the layer in one column[image]
If you have three titles and two columns the will be two layers on a row and the third one below it[image]
If you have three layers and three columns the all be on a row and so on[image]